# Unable to upload video longer than 1 minute

Tags: iphone, file-upload, nsurlrequest

I am working on application which require a video upload functionality. I am using     NSURLRequest for this and its working fine for video which is less then 1 minute in length, but cause problem when video is large. Do any one have any idea about that???

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"----F00";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[mediaDict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"data[file_name]\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Content-Type: %@\r\n\r\n",fileContentType] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:fileData];

[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if (theConnection) {

    // Create the NSMutableData to hold the received data.

    // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.

    self.receivedData = [NSMutableData data];

} else {
    // Inform the user that the connection failed.
    UIAlertView *didFailWithErrorMessage = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"NSURLConnection " message: @"didFailWithError"  delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [didFailWithErrorMessage show];
    [spinnerView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

I really appreciate your help friends.

Comment: "cause problem when video is large"... do you have any more specific info?

Comment: Hi joachim. I am using     UIImagePicker to capture video and if that video is longer then 1 min, the video is not uploaded to server. the snippet i wrote above working fine for video which is less than 1 min. Sorry for my bad english. Hope you understand what i want to explain

Comment: Where are you uploading the video to? Any limits on the receiver side?

Answer (score 0):

Set the timeout interval and check whether its working or not

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setTimeoutInterval:6000];
```

Comment: What is the size of video ?

Comment: Any thing larger then 1 minute.... Dont know the size in Mega Bytes. Do ios have any restriction about MB Data?